# chrome and swf caching

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swfobject

I change my swf, but chrome just keep on loading the old swf.
I tried to add METAs (pragma, no cache etc..) on the php file that hosts the swf. I also added some headers to force not using cache on chrome.

But It keeps on loading OLD swf. 
Finally I renamed the SWF: that helped, but this is really not the right solution.

Can someone help me with chrome and swf caching trouble ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was a reported bug in old versions of Chrome that Meta's such as `Cache-Control`, `Pragma`, `Expires`, etc don't work in Chrome. Therefore, it was confirmed on Google Chrome up to version 5.x.x that F5 and CTRL+F5 don't refresh SWF files with Flash version 10,x,x. You can read the discussions of the caching bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035)

One solution I came across is that instead of using `"cache-control: no-cache"` in the header of your host php file, you can use `"cache-control: no-store"`. This seemed to worked for plenty of developers (haven't tested this myself)

Answer (score 1):

You can force swf to be reloaded every time by selecting the "Disable cache" setting through Chrome's debug settings (the little gear at the bottom right corner when the developer tool is open).